# How to check if the same image or another image or something other than the image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am making a sortable and resizable image album. In there, I am trying to add a feature to create the image as a link.

1. Image is clicked
2. Then wrap that image with a div which displays an edit button on top of that image.
3. And when the edit button is clicked a dialog box will appear to enter the url and name for that image.
4. And then wrap the image with an `a tag` with the given url and name.

Demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tikz/cmr8Ljp5/)

This is ok. But what I would like to do is:

- If same image is clicked don't wrap the edit div again.
- Only if a new image is clicked wrap the edit div.
- And if something other than the image is clicked remove the edit div.

How can I achieve this? I think unwrap() will the trick to remove the edit div from the image but how will I know if it is the same image, or something other than that?

js snippet:

```
$('#sortable li img').on("click", function () {
    $image = $(this);
    image_resize($image);
    edit_image($image);
});

function edit_image(image) {
    image.wrap('<div id="edit-image"></div>');
    $('#edit-image').prepend('<a href="#">EDIT</a>');
    $("#edit-image a").center(true).css("cursor", "pointer").css("z-index", "1");
    $('#edit-image a').on("click", function () {
        alert("clicked on edit");
        if (image.parent().is("a")) {
            var img_link = image.parent().attr("href");
            var img_name = image.parent().attr("alt");
            $('#image_link_dialog #input #link').val(img_link);
            $('#image_link_dialog #input #name').val(img_name);
        }
        $('#image_link_dialog').css("display", "block").css("z-index", "2");
        $('#image_link_dialog').center(false);
        $('#image_link_dialog').draggable();
    });
    $('#image_link_dialog .dialog_handle a').on("click", function () {
        if (!$('#image_link_dialog #input #name').val() == '') {
            var img_name = $('#image_link_dialog #input #name').val();
            console.log('img_name: ' + img_name);
        }
        if (!$('#image_link_dialog #input #link').val() == '') {
            var img_link = $('#image_link_dialog #input #link').val();
            console.log('img_link: ' + img_link);
            if (img_name) {
                if (image.parent().is("a")) {
                    image.parent().attr("alt", img_name);
                    image.parent().attr("href", img_link);
                } else {
                    image.wrap(function () {
                        return "<a class='img_a' href='" + img_link + "' alt='" + img_name + "'></a>";
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if (image.parent().is("a")) {
                    image.parent().attr("href", img_link);
                } else {
                    image.wrap(function () {
                        return "<a class='img_a' href='" + img_link + "'></a>";
                    })
                }

            }
        } else {
            alert('please enter link url');
        }
        $('#image_link_dialog #input #link').val('');
        $('#image_link_dialog #input #name').val('');
        $('#image_link_dialog').css("display", "none");
    })
}
```

Comment: just assign an attribute you can check

Comment: @WhiteHat Like? What attribute?

Comment: @TikliTaba just add a class or attribute like "wrapped" or "edit-mode" and check for that in click handler function. If the attribute or class you add is available then don't wrap.

Comment: Just make one up, data-clicked

Comment: in your (<img) tags add <img data-edited="false") when click to edit or whenever grammatically set it to (<img data-edited="true"). You can read or set whats inside data-edited by using (.attr). Then its a case of (if false > edit) (if true > dont edit)

Comment: @Tasos ok i will try that. But I also want to be able to edit false when other than the image is clicked.

Comment: @Yogita088 And how to check if other than the image is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your fiddle to demonstrate a possible solution:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyf7p86r/3/)

To check wether a image is currently edited i add a class. This later helps me to identify the currently edited image.
I added alerts to show when you have to stop the edit mode.

The following snippet allows you to catch the event of clicking anything but an image.

```
$(document).on("click", function (event) {
     alert('stop edit for current image'); 
});
```

Adding `event.stopPropagation()` to the onCLick of the images stops the `$(document).on("click",...` from capturing this click as well.

Comment: I made some modification on your code to unwrap and remove both div and a tag from the image, but its not working as supposed to. Could you please look into that. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tikz/pLk9kuo2/3/)

Comment: i added an id to the edit anchor. now it should do what you want it to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLk9kuo2/4/) (EDIT: changed Link to fiddle)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid adding multiple wrappers you can do something like this:

```
$('li.ui-sortable-handle').click(function(){
     $('li.ui-sortable-handle').removeClass('edit-image'); //remove previously selected images
     $(this).addClass('edit-image');
});
```

And to do editing :

```
$('body').on('click','.edit-image', function(){
    //do whatever you want. the click event is as example edit and it to any event that suits you
});
```

To remove edit flag if something else is clicked:

```
$('body').on('click','*',function(e){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('.ui-sortable-handle') $('li.ui-sortable-handle').removeClass('edit-image');
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

of course I suggest adding another class other than `ui-sortable-handle` to you `li`s and use them in the above code as there might be other elements with class 'ui-sortable-handle' in your page.

Comment: Could you please elaborate using jsfiddle.